# How can I test PCR model?

Tags: pca, predictive-models, matlab

I'm new to modeling principle component regression. I used MATLAB documentation to see an example on how to do it using the built-in functions.
I just want to know how to test the model to try other examples than the training set.

This is the piece of code I want to investigate:

```
[PCALoadings,PCAScores,PCAVar] = princomp(X); %,'Economy',false);
betaPCR = regress(y-mean(y), PCAScores(:,1:2));
betaPCR = PCALoadings(:,1:2)*betaPCR;
betaPCR = [mean(y) - mean(X)*betaPCR; betaPCR];
yfitPCR = [ones(n,1) X]*betaPCR;
```

I think `X` should be the `X` that I want to test. The question is, what is `y` here? This `y` I don't know, I actually want to predict it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking my TA, I found that pca should be applied to `X` which should be the data I want to train. After that, the fitted `y` is a linear combination of the `X` that I want to test with the coefficients I got from the pca.